# How to transpose many files Given that linesWithFileNames: RDD[(Path, Text)], which Text contains a matrix?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I want to input many files and construct a *pair(Array[String],Index)* for each column, the index could be "file-i" where i is local column counter.

For example:

```
tableA.txt:00 01 02\n10 11 12

tableB.txt:03 04\n13 14
```

Target(each column with its filename and index):

```
RDD[Array[String],String] : (Array("00","10"),"tableA.txt-0"),(Array("01","11","tableA.txt-1"),(Array("02","12"),"tableA.txt-2"),(Array("03","13"),"tableB.txt-0"),(Array("04","14"),"tableB.txt-1")
```

My code:

```
    val fc = classOf[TextInputFormat]
    val kc = classOf[LongWritable]
    val vc = classOf[Text]
    val text = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path, fc ,kc, vc, sc.hadoopConfiguration)
    val linesWithFileNames = text.asInstanceOf[NewHadoopRDD[LongWritable, Text]]
      .mapPartitionsWithInputSplit((inputSplit, iterator) => {
        val file = inputSplit.asInstanceOf[FileSplit]
        iterator.map(tup => (file.getPath, tup._2))
      })
    val columnsData = linesWithFileNames.flatMap(p => {
      val filename = p._1.toString
      val lines = p._2.toString.split("\n")
      lines.map(l => l.split(" "))
           .toSeq.transpose.zipWithIndex
           .map(pair => (pair._1, filename+"-"+pair._2.toString))
    })
```

My wrong result:

```
("00","tableA.txt-0"),("10","tableA.txt-0")...
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to achieve what you want is to use `wholeTextFiles` which generates a RDD that associates each file path to its content.

The code would look like this:

```scala
val result : RDD[(Array[String], String)] = sc
    .wholeTextFiles("data1")
    .flatMap{ case (path, lines) => lines
        .split("\\n")
        .zipWithIndex
        .map{ case (line, i) => (line.split("\\s+"),
                                 path.split("/").last + "-" + i)}
    }
```

Comment: thank u, but wholeTextFiles() is suitable for many but small files, which large file will cause JVM memory error. I give up the way described as above.. to use a distribute version like:b.flatMap(_.zipWithIndex)
  .groupBy(_._2)
  .mapValues(_.map(_._1))
  .collectAsMap()
  .toList
  .sortBy(_._1)
  .map(_._2)